# Как определить где закончились аргументы вариативной функции

Tags: c++, c, функции, matlab, параметры

Пытаюсь портировать функцию Matlab-а на c++. В исходной функции, в качестве второго аргумента передавалась переменная типа *cell* (нечто вроде динамической структуры, такой контейнер, куда можно положить что угодно любого типа и в любом числе). Данные в этой ячейке лежат в следующем порядке: строка, число, строка, число и т.д. При этом число таких пар произвольно, данных может и вовсе не быть.

После, строки последовательно парсятся, и, если они совпадают с названием параметра, мы инициализируем этот параметр числом, идущим за строкой.
Загвоздка в том, что может потребоваться любая комбинация из входных параметров, поэтому скажем, указать в функции по порядку переменные и передавать туда в том же порядке одни лишь значения не получится.

В итоге я пришел к мысли, что нужно писать вариативную функцию, использующую *stdarg.h*. Почитал об этом заголовочном файле, в целом вроде все понял, за исключением того, можно ли понять где заканчивается список переданных аргументов (имеется ввиду, без костылей вроде указания заранее числа переданных далее аргументов, или какого-нибудь магического числа, по которому мы поймем, что здесь завершается список аргументов).

Во всех описаниях stdarg пишется, что самой часто используемой функцией, которая включает этот заголовочный файл является printf, и ведь ей мы не передаем никаких магических параметров в конце, никакого числа параметров в начале, если параметров недостаточно, она отрабатывает ту часть, которую мы определили параметрами, как надо, остальную уже как получится. Если мы передадим ей слишком много параметров, она тоже не возмутится и просто выполнит то что нужно.

Comment: Если вам требуется динамическая структура значений строка-число , то это std::map или, например, std::vector структур с двумя полями: строка и число

Comment: printf первым аргументом получает строку формата по которой она отлично понимает какие аргументы ожидать после этого. лишние аргументы она просто проигнорирует. а если их не хватит то у вас будет UB из за того что printf примет за параметры что то к ним не относящееся в стеке. так что никакой магии. функция сама решает откуда ей взять информацию о количестве и типах параметров.

Comment: @tilin, да, я думал об этом, просто хотелось бы обойти шаг с упаковкой аргументов в какой-либо контейнер, и вместо этого просто сразу передавать их в функцию.

Comment: Если ваш компилятор поддерживает C++ 11, то там для подобных вещей есть шаблоны с переменным числом аргументов, кортежи (std::tuple). Рассматривали?

Comment: @Mike, я подозревал что так и есть, но надеялся, что все же есть какой-то механизм, который сообщит сам, сколько было передано аргументов.

Comment: @Voidificator, нет, сейчас гляну, спасибо за наводку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цитата из доки:

> Возможно передавать структуру va_list другим поддерживаемым функциям
>   для ручного перебора аргументов функции. Это можно сделать как-то так:

```
int sum_many(int first, ...)
    __attribute__((sentinel(0)));

int sum_many(int first, ...)
{
    int num, ret = first;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, first);
    while ( (num = va_arg(ap, int)) != NULL) {
       ret += num;
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return ret;
}
```

> Каждый вызов va_arg будет возвращать следующий параметр. Функция
>   va_arg требует имя типа (или указатель на имя типа), для того, что бы
>   преобразовать параметр к нужному типу.
>
> Атрибут sentinel(0) заставляет компилятор выполнять проверку
>   параметра, находящегося в позиции 0 (последний параметр функции),
>   действительно является NULL.

Кроме того, поскольку Вы пишите для С++, в котором всегда есть один дополнительный параметр при вызове функций, то необходимо это учитывать. Опять-же, цитата из доки:

> Если Вы пишите функцию с переменным числом параметров в C++, Вы будете
>   думать, что это правильно :

```
class A {
...
    int myprintf(const char *fmt, ...)
        __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));
};
```

> Атрибут формата должен использовать первый параметр, как строку
>   форматирования и второй - как переменную часть. При компиляции GCC
>   выдаст следующее сообщение об ошибке:

```
error: format string argument not a string type
```

> Разумеется, это происходит в следствии того факта, что C++ имеет один
>   дополнительный параметр у каждого члена класса. Поэтому правильное
>   объявление метода должно выглядеть так:

```
class A {
...
    int myprintf(const char *fmt, ...)
        __attribute__((format(printf, 2, 3)));
};
```